# Data separated by column in C# from a text file

Tags: c#, console-application, tabular

[File txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e04zG.png)

I have this file in text and need to organize ordered in table.
OBS: need to be console app c #

I did it only:

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"filepatch.txt");
        string ler = sr.ReadLine();
        string linha = ";";
        int cont = 0;


        while((linha = sr.ReadLine())!= null)
        {

            string col = linha.Split(';')[2];
            cont++;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", cont, linha);

        }
```

Comment: Can  you show a line of sample data?

Comment: What is the desired result? What do you expect from your app?

Comment: You probably should do something with the variable `col`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the file text:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"filepatch.txt");
```

Then you can use the returned `string[]` to carry out the rest of your logic.

```
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    string[] cols = line.Split(';');
    // Your logic here.  
}
```

Cheers!